# List-style and float not working on grid boxes with CSS

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Might be a bit too early in the morning for me but I struggling to figure out what I've done wrong here.

I have a page with 9 boxes and I would like them to be positioned with 3 on one line, 3 on another and 3 on the other.

Have a look here: http://dev.tim-morgan.co.uk/other/Untitled-1.html

Right now you can see, the list bullets are showing and each box looks like it's going down like a staircase since I put in float: left;

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- Move `float: left` from `ul.tabs2 a` to `ul.tabs2 li`.
- Add `overflow: hidden` to `.tabs2` to clear the floats.
- Add `clear: left` to every `3n+1` `li` using [`:nth-child`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild), try this:

  ```
  ul.tabs2 li:nth-child(3n+1) {
      clear: left
  }
  ```

If you need to support Internet Explorer 8 and lower (no `nth-child` support), you can use http://selectivizr.com/, or just add the `clear: left` rule yourself to each relevant `li`.

Comment: +1 for nice solution, but still requires additional plugin for crossbrowser.

Comment: @easwee: Thanks. What additional plugin? I already mentioned selectivizr.

Comment: That's what I'm reffering too - I would rather achieve crossbrowser stability with css only. But still if performance is not really the issue this is probably cleanest.

Comment: thanks, I tried what you said. Please refresh the page to see what I done, and the list bullets are still there. Any ideas now?

Comment: @Tim: You still need to do `ul.tabs2 { list-style: none; }`. I didn't bother adding it to my answer because @Paul D. Waite already covered it with a nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to remove the default styles on your `<li>`s, they could be interfering with the floating of the `<a>`s in the `<li>`s.

I’d suggest:

```
ul.tabs2 {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs2 li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

For getting three in a row, [@thirydot’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592698/list-style-and-float-not-working-on-grid-boxes-with-css/5592738#5592738) looks good. If you know how wide you want each box to be, you could set that width on the `<a>`s, then set a width on the `<ul>`:

```
ul.tabs2 {
    width: 300px;
}

ul.tabs2 li a {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This does work (+1) for fixing the staircase issue, but I think it makes more sense to float the `li` elements.

Comment: @thirtydot But this won't make 3 li elements on each row.

Comment: @easwee: It doesn't matter if you float the `li` or the `a` elements, with respect to getting three in a row. You still need to clear elements, see my answer.

Comment: @thirtydot: yeah, I’d agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

In your css add this

```
ul.tabs2 li {display:block;float:left;width:33%;margin:0 0 10px 0;padding:0;}
```

and also add `overflow:hidden` and `list-style:none` to your `ul.tabs2` if you don't want bullets.